# Hardhat, ether.js - fetching balance of signers locally shows no ether

Tags: balances, ethers.js, hardhat

I am trying to fetch the balance of signers in a test locally. I didn't change the default value of eth for accounts in the hardhat configuration. Yet when I query the balance, I see that the accounts do not have any balance.

Here is my code:

```
        [owner, alice, bob, chuck, ...others] = await ethers.getSigners();
        
        provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();

        balance = await provider.getBalance(owner.address);
        console.log(balance.toString()); // 0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was the provider returned by `getDefaultProvider` connected to the main net, while I was trying to test locally.
I ended up at this conclusion by calling the `getNetwork` call on the provider, seeing that the network being used was in fact, the main net.

To fix this, I looked up hardhat docs, and hardhat provides a custom provider in ethers object which can be accessed using `ethers.provider`.

So the fix was using:

```
    provider = ethers.provider;
```

Comment: this helped me get account balance.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running tests on hardhat and trying to fetch balance of an address. The best way to get your actual balance is:

```
 import { ethers } from 'hardhat'


 const provider = ethers.provider;
 const balance = await provider.getBalance("pasteYourAddressHere");

// returns BigNumber { value: someValueInWei }
```

You'll want to make sure you are inside an async function to get the best out of this code block. Using  `provider.getDefaultProvider()` returns an Ethereum mainnet provider.